# Programmatically added items to FlowLayoutPanel aren't aligned like those at design time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Here is the panel prior to programmatic insertion:

[image: The labels at runtime before programmatic add]

And after:

[image: The labels after programmatic insertion]

I've added other lines copying from the Review label styling hoping it was a padding or margins issue. Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be the case. To clarify, the FlowLayoutPanel itself extends to the right a good distance beyond what the new label should need as shown here:

[image: Bounds of FlowLayoutPanel]

All the other `Label`s are `AutoSize` enabled.

Here's the code for generation and insertion:

```
Label newLabel = new Label();
newLabel.Name = optionString;
newLabel.Text = type;
newLabel.Font = ReviewLabel.Font; // just a random label. only thing that matters is consistent styling.
newLabel.ForeColor = ReviewLabel.ForeColor;
newLabel.Margin = ReviewLabel.Margin;
newLabel.Padding = ReviewLabel.Padding;

LabelsPanel.Controls.Add(typeLabel);
```

`optionString` is `type` with the spaces removed. `type`'s value is 'Terms Of Service.' Thanks for any help.

Edit: Here's illustrating how much space there is if I define a `Label` at design time by just dragging a `Label` from the controls panel onto the form and setting the `Size` and `Text` properties.

[image: Design time Terms label]

[image: Runtime Terms label]

Comment: My first guess is that Terms of Service is wide enough that it's wrapping instead of staying on one line, causing it to become too tall. Try setting `type` to a shorter value, to see if it is word wrapping causing your headache. If that is the problem, you may need to programatically set the width on the label to ensure it doesn't wrap.

Comment: I created another label at design time that had the same `Text` value and it didn't wrap or cause weird issues. There was plenty of room to spare on the right, and it looked as I would expect lining up with the others. I'll redo that test case and edit with an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Note at [Label.AutoSize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97064ew3(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When added to a form using the designer, the default value is true.
>   When instantiated from code, the default value is false.

So you probably need to add:

```
newLabel.AutoSize = true;
```

Comment: Indeed. I just tried it, but, to me, that wasn't intuitive. I'll mark your answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `AutoSize` on `Label` controls aren't set to `true` by default when you new one up in code. Setting that solved the issue. While consistent with how booleans default values behave, it's different from the default behavior you see when you interact with the designer. That was the disconnect.